# How to parse succesfully a utf-16le encoded jsonfile with haxe on the php target?

Tags: haxe

I have some third party application that I have to use, it generates UTF16LE encoded json files.
When I put these manually on my server and try haxe generated php to parse these files, it refuses. It seems it can't detect and convert to the encoding haxe php accepts.

I don't know where to start. Converting it on the client is an impossibility, there are too many of such files and need too frequently be parsed. So I have to use php. It would be nice if haxe has a way to convert it to the encoding it accepts. I have tried RTFM, but I so far I havent found anything that says haxe can convert it. Before I start reinventing some second wheel, I rather make sure there isn't some obvious way to it with haxe.

I am using Haxe version 4.2.1+bf9ff69

What am I overlooking? Is haxe php able to solve this, or is going native php the only option?

== SOLVED ==

As these json files do not need any emoticon support or whatever characters for non-english language, my solution was to strip everything except basic printable ASCII characters.

```
import sys.io.File;
import php.Syntax;

// some function body
return Syntax.code('preg_replace( "/[^[:print:]]/", "",{0})',File.getContent(_path));
```

I couldn't share these file on the web, because of privacy concerns. Also I discovered these files had ... wait for it - double BOM's- hacked into it.The BOM detector I threw in reported the first BOM it found happening to be UTF16LE.
Enterprise spaghetti monster probably the reason. Thought I had seen it all, but with that, one probably can't never have seen it all. The wonders of human ingenuity.

Just a blunt strip instead of making my own ludicrous code to unfudge that stuff and justice served. Hurrah.

Comment: got some code which you're using to parse the files with?